# NoMethodError (undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

We are getting the above mentioned error, not quite sure why.  We are building API for a quiz website, and this is our logins_controller:

```
 class Api::LoginsController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_action :verify_authentication

    def create
        user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
        if  user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
            render json: { name: user.name, token: user.token }
        else
            render json: user.errors
        end
    end
 end
```

Our schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "token"
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["token"], name: "index_users_on_token", unique: true
  end
```

Error message in terminal:

```
Started POST "/api/logins" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-23 18:30:48 -0400
Processing by Api::LoginsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"login"=>{}}
  User Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/logins_controller.rb:6
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/api/logins_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

This was working just fine, then all of a sudden it says user is nil?  Have we not defined it under create.

Comment: It looks like the `else` part of your statement in the `create` method does not validate that there is a `user` so it could end up being nil by the looks of it.

Comment: I'm testing on postman with a user i've created that's showing up in the database.  And it was something that was working previously.

Comment: It looks like the params are empty `Parameters: {"login"=>{}}` so no username is being provided `User Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL ...` and thus no user is being found.  I am assuming the user's data was passed in the params.  Any code changes lately that may have altered that?

Comment: Looked through some codes, didnt' alter much, but simply changing user to @user everywhere seemed to get it working!

Comment: Right, it is probably an instance variable created somewhere, not a local variable like you have there.  Glad it is working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked through some codes, didn't alter much, but simply changing user to @user everywhere seemed to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

When the parameter `:username` doesn't match any user, the `user` variable will be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't send any parameters to the controller

In your terminal: `Parameters: {"login"=>{}}`

```
user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
```

so the `user` variable will be nil

Answer (score 0):

If a user with username is not exists in your database, the following code will return `nil`

```
user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
```

As a result, you will get `undefined method errors` when calling `user.errors`